# Symfony 2.8 : How to format date time form type?

Tags: symfony

I have created a datetime in form type Symfony :

```
$builder->add(
    'dateFrom',
    'datetime',
    [
        'widget'     => 'single_text',
        'label'      => 'Form',
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'control-label'],
        'attr' => [
            'class'        => 'form-control date-from',
            'data-toggle'  => 'date',
            'autocomplete' => 'off'
        ],
        'format'     => 'YYYY-MM-dd',
        'input'      => 'datetime',
        'required'   => false,

    ]
);
```

But its default is from 1950 to 2050. Now I want to reformat the time display from 1950 (or 2000) to current year. Please help me? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6qGq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony provides a [Birthday form type](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/birthday.html) that might be closer to what you want:

> This type is essentially the same as the DateType type, but with a more appropriate default for the years option. The years option defaults to 120 years ago to the current year.

Alternatively you can set the [`years` option](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#years):

```php
$builder->add(
    'dateFrom',
    'datetime',
    [
        'widget' => 'choice', // the years option is only relevant for choice
        'years' => range(1950, (int) date('Y')),
        ...
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am having one more problem that is when I choose a date. example: 2020-12-29 , but it's out of date : 2021-12-29 . Please tell me the reason

Comment: If you limit the year-range to the current year (2020) then I would expect this to be correct. Otherwise, please check your request, e.g. in your browser's dev tools (under network), if the date is sent to you in the expected format. If you use a JS-datepicker it might need some config to send the data in the expected format. You have to make sure both sides (frontend and backend) use the same format.